# Inline labels for exposed filter forms in Views 3

Tags: 7, views

How do I make labels inline for exposed forms in Views 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be worth checking out the [Better Exposed Filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module, and [Better Exposed Filters](http://drupal.org/node/766974) (the handbook). I haven't used this module.

Comment: Actually, now I have used this module. Works Great.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a small module (or already have one), you could use the [form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) (or rather the form_FORM_ID_alter) hook to add the "container-inline" class.

Here is some sample code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()
 *
 * Display views 3.x exposed filters' field labels and fields inline
 */
function mymodule_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  // If you want to only affect specific views' exposed forms, select the view name here
  if ($form_state['view']->name == 'myviewname') {
    // Add a class to the attributes
    $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'container-inline';
  }
}
```

Replace "mymodule" with your custom module name.

Replace "myviewname" with the view's machine name, or remove the if statement completely to affect all exposed filter forms.